# Form Submits After Every Page Refresh/Site Visit (PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a HTML form within my site and, on every page refresh and site visit, the form submits and sends me a blank email. Even stranger, I have form validation and required fields within my form and when I click the submit button the required field checks and other validations run accordingly but, when I refresh the page -with a form blank, no inputs- it submits the form and I get a blank email -how is it able to submit the form on page refresh with no values entered? Hope this is clear... Below is my PHP and HTML form. Thank you!

```
<?php // define variables and set to empty values
            $nameErr = $emailErr = "";
            $name = $email = $comment = "";

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
              if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                $nameErr = "*Name is required";
              } else {
                $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                  $nameErr = "*Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                }
              }

              if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $emailErr = "*Email is required";
              } else {
                $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                  $emailErr = "*Invalid email format"; 
                }
              }

              if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
                $comment = "";
              } else {
                $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
              }


            }

            function test_input($data) {
              $data = trim($data);
              $data = stripslashes($data);
              $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
              return $data;
            }




            if(empty($nameErr) && empty($emailErr))
                {
                    $myemail = 'doreen.jones@flavoredesign.com';
                    $name = $_POST['name']; 
                    $email = $_POST['email']; 
                    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
                    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                    $budget = $_POST['budget'];
                    $timeline = $_POST['timeline'];
                    $services = implode(', ', $_POST['services']);
                    $comment = $_POST['comment']; 
                    $source = $_POST['source'];

                    $to = $myemail; 
                    $email_subject = "A Message From: $name \n \n";

                    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
                    "Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Company Name: $company_name \n Telephone: $phone \n Services of Interest: $services \n Budget: $budget \n Timeline: $timeline \n Message:  $comment \n Source: $source"; 

                    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
                    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

                    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
                    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
                    header('Location: http://flavoredesign.com/index.php#contact_sec');
                } 


                if(empty($nameErr) && empty($emailErr) && !empty($name) && !empty($email)) {
                    echo "<p class='thank_you'>Thank you! Your message has been received. A Flavoredesign representative will be in touch with you shortly!</p>";

                }

            ?>
```

And Html is

```
<div id="contact_form">
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>#contact_sec" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="padding-left:0px !important;">
          <span class="error">
            <?php echo $nameErr;?>
          </span>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Your Name*" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
          <span class="error">
            <?php echo $emailErr;?>
          </span>
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder=" Your Email*" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="padding-right:0px !important;">
          <input type="text" name="company_name" placeholder=" Company Name">
          <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder=" Phone Number">
        </div>
      </div>   
      <br/>
      <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;">
        <div class="col-12"> 
          <label>What services are you interested in? (select all that apply)
          </label>
          <div id="checkboxes">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="services[]" value="Website Design">
                <label for="c1">Website Design
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="services[]" value="UI/UX Design">
                <label for="c3">UI/UX Design
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="c5" name="services[]" value="Print Design">
                <label for="c5">Print Design
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="c6" name="services[]" value="Logo & Identity Design">
                <label for="c6">Logo & Identity Design
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="c8" name="services[]" value="SEO & Marketing">
                <label for="c8">SEO & Marketing
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="padding-left:0px !important;">
          <select name="budget">
            <option selected="selected"> What's your budget?
            </option>
            <option value="-500"> less than $1,000
            </option>
            <option value="1000to5000"> $1,000 to $5,000
            </option>
            <option value="5000to10000"> $5,000 to $10,000
            </option>
            <option value="+10000"> more than $10,000
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="padding-right:0px !important;">
          <input type="text" name="timeline" placeholder=" How soon do you need your project completed?">
        </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="padding-right:0px !important; padding-left:0px !important;">  
          <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Questions? Details? What else would you like me to know?"
                    <?php echo $comment;?>>
          </textarea>
        <select name="source">
          <option selected="selected"> Where did you hear about Flavoredesign?
          </option>
          <option value="online search"> online search
          </option>
          <option value="from a friend"> from a friend
          </option>
          <option value="social media"> social media
          </option>
          <option value="media advertisment"> media advertisement
          </option>
          <option value="other"> other
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div id="submit">
    <button type="submit" id="contact_button" class="buttons hvr-ripple-out">Submit
    </button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are reloading with the post data in it. You should set the posting route to other file and redirect to the last page after doing your backend operation

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to PHP. What would what you are describing look like? I understand that I'd change my header (Location:...) to somewhere other than the original index.php but, how do I then redirect the user back to the index.php and render the thank you message and scroll to my #contact_sec? Thank you for your reply!